# Performance - Delete multiple MSSQL database entries with LINQ

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I have got a MSSQL database table with a few million entries.
Every new entry got an ID +1 from the last entry. That means that lower ID numbers are older entries. Now I want to delete old entries in the database with the help of it's ID.
I delete every "Entry" that is lower than the "maxID".

```
while (true)
{
    List<Entry> entries = entity.Entry.Where(z => z.id < maxID).Take(1000).ToList();

    foreach (var entry in entries)
    {
        entity.Entry.DeleteObject(entry);
    }

    if (entries < 1000)
    {
        break;
    }
}
```

I can't take all entries with one query because this would raise a System.OutOfMemoryException. So I only took 1000 entries and repeat the delete function until every entry is deleted.

My question is: What would be the best number of entries to ".Take()" in performance?

Answer (score 1):

It's faster to drop and recreate the tables in the database, 
You can directly execute commands against the database by calling your stored procedure using
[ExecuteStoreQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd487208.aspx) method.

Any commands automatically generated by the Entity Framework may be more complex than similar commands written explicitly by a database developer. If you need explicit control over the commands executed against your data source, consider defining a mapping to a table-valued function or stored procedure. -[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc853327%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

As i can see your code (Please correct me if i am wrong or improve the answer), Your code is actually loading entities in memory which is an overhead cost because you need to perform delete operation ,and your query will create delete query for each entity marked by
`DeleteObject`. So in terms of performance it will be better to call a stored procedure and execute your query directly against the database.

[ExecuteStoreCommand Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.objectcontext.executestorecommand%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

[Directly Execute commands](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358769%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I do not want to drop the table. I only want to delete entries with lower ids.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
entity.Entry.Where(z => z.id < maxID).ToList().ForEach(entity.Entry.DeleteObject);
entity.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: It does not work. This also raises the System.OutOfMemoryException while trying to SaveChanges() on entity.